# Evitar inyección de código pero permitir etiqueta script para tweets embebidos

Tags: php, html, twitter

Tengo una sección de comentarios en mi web, y para que no me inyecten código o al menos evitarlo en la mayor medida de lo posible, no permito entre otras etiquetas la etiqueta `<script>`. Uso la siguiente función para ello:

```
function evitamos_script($texto) {

    $limpia = strip_tags($texto, '<b> <i> <u> <quote> <img> <center> <cite> <a> <div> <a> <blockquote>'); //EVITAMOS SCRIPTS

    return $limpia;
}
```

Funciona bien. El problema es que me gustaría, por ejemplo, que los usuarios puedan compartir tuits, embeberlos en el comentario. Este código lo obtiene cada usuario desde Twitter, en el menú `Insertar tweet`, lo copia y lo pega en el mensaje.

El código que pega, al llevar la etiqueta `<script>` al final, no lo permite, y en vez de aparecer un tuit embebido sale simplemente texto.

¿Hay alguna forma de solucionar esto?

El script para embeber tuits sería por ejemplo:

```
<script async src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

---

Pongo un ejemplo de lo que pegaría un usuario, poniendo en un comentario por ejemplo el siguiente texto (y el `<script>` al final):

```
<blockquote class="twitter-tweet" data-lang="es">¡Semana de Indies en Xbox! Decenas de juegos en oferta temporal. Ya tenéis los Deals With Gold de esta semana.<a href="https://t.co/kj95gnhlBK">https://t.co/kj95gnhlBK</a>— LaXtore (@LaXtore) <a href="https://twitter.com/LaXtore/status/877010505570947072">20 de junio de 2017</a></blockquote> <script async src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

La idea es que ese script se ejecute, para conseguir este resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Obviamente, sin permitir que los usuarios puedan abusar de mi sistema.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta. ¿Estoy mirando pero es más para permitir el tipo de caracteres que quieres permitir no?

Comment: Se me ocurre que te sería más práctico utilizar herramientas ya creadas a este efecto. Por ejemplo, el blog de [se] utiliza https://disqus.com/

Comment: Gracias, pero ya estuve usando Disqus y no me gustaba porque me llenaba la web de publicidad y comentarios de otros usuarios. Independientemente de eso no es sólo por salir del paso, sino por aprender.

Comment: JetLagFox: entiendo y te honra la voluntad de aprender :) ¿Podrías añadir a la pregunta el formato exacto que tiene el código que embebe un tuit?

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo con fedorqui, ¿por qué no usar algo ya establecido que no te genere dolores de cabeza con cada actualización?... De todas formas, si te interesa reinventar la rueda, por qué no permitirles que agreguen la url del tweet, y transformarla al código que sea desde tu código? O, si preferís que usen tags, proponerles que usen un tag personalizado como `<twitter>` desde el que tomarías el enlace.

Comment: He editado la pregunta para mostrarlo. He probado añadiendo también la etiqueta `<script async src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8">` para que la permita pero no me ha funcionado.

Comment: @Mariano hago eso con otras etiquetas como `<img>`. El problema es que aunque haga eso, antes o después voy a tener que traducirlo a la etiqueta <script> y me la va a rechazar. Lo único que se me ocurre es que a la base de datos introduzca la etiqueta `<twitter>` por ejemplo sin traducir, y que al cargar el comentario lo traduzca ya al script. Es la única solución que le veo, para que no pase por el filtro.

Comment: @JetLagFox siguiendo la primera opción (con la URL), la idea es que primero limpies los tags, y luego agregues el script

Comment: @Mariano imagino que te refieres a agregar el script una cuando cargue los mensajes. Pero pensándolo, no se me ocurre cómo hacerlo, porque hay información como el contenido el título del tuit que imagino que se consigo parseándolo.

Comment: Puedes poner un ejemplo de que comentario pondría un usuario en el cual vaya compartir un tweet?

Comment: No desde el sevidor, el cliente tiene que obtener los tweets con su propia cuenta... De todas formas, ya nos estamos yendo por las ramas (se hace imposible responder)... Creo que deberías decidir una estrategia y mostrar en la pregunta cuál es el texto inicial (el comentario del usuario), y el resultado esperado (impreso por PHP)... Así podemos buscarle la solución.

Comment: @Mariano Tienes razón. Acabo de editar para que quede clara la pregunta.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Objetivo

Lo que estás queriendo hacer es permitir que un usuario inserte un tweet desde el código que te da Twitter desde el menú de cada tweet.

> [image: menú de twitter para insertar]

que genera un código como el siguiente:

```
<blockquote class="twitter-tweet" data-lang="es">
    <p lang="es" dir="ltr">
        ¡Stack Overflow en español se gradúa hoy!
        <a href="https://t.co/2UcOEoIS0V">https://t.co/2UcOEoIS0V</a>
    </p>
    &mdash; SO en Español (@esStackOverflow)
    <a href="https://twitter.com/esStackOverflow/status/864815633447485442">17 de mayo de 2017</a>
</blockquote>
<script async src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Veamos, tiene las etiquetas `<blockquote>`, `<p>`, `<a>` y `<script>`.

A los usuarios ya les estás permitiendo incluir todas estas etiquetas excepto `<script>`. Sin embargo, el script es siempre el mismo para todos los tweets. Es el que se encarga de convertir todos los `blockquote.twitter-tweet` al formato deseado.

#### Propuesta

La mejor solución en este caso, me parece que:

1. Efectivamente elimines el `<script>` agregado por el usuario.
2. Agregues la línea

   ```
   <script async src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
   ```

   al final de la página.

#### Código

Sería, a modo general, de la siguiente forma:

```
//Seguimos eliminando los scripts
function evitamos_script($texto) {
    $limpia = strip_tags($texto, '<b><i><u><quote><img><center><cite><a><div><blockquote>'); //EVITAMOS SCRIPTS
    //deberías hacer algo más acá para evitar inyección de código
    //no alcanza con strip_tags()
    return $limpia;
}

//Imprimimos todos los mensajes limpios
foreach ($mensajes as &$un_mensaje) {
    echo '<div>Todo lo que esté antes de cada mensaje</div>';

    echo evitamos_script($un_mensaje);

    echo '<div>Todo lo que esté después de cada mensaje</div>';
}

// Incluimos el script una sola vez en el HTML, y que formatee a todos los tweets.
echo '<script async src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>';
```

#### Resultado

O sea, que te quedaría una página como esta por ejemplo:

```html
<div>Todo lo que esté antes de cada mensaje</div>
Este es el mensaje del usuario, que incluyó el tweet:
<blockquote class="twitter-tweet" data-lang="es"><p lang="es" dir="ltr">¡Stack Overflow en español se gradúa hoy! <a href="https://t.co/2UcOEoIS0V">https://t.co/2UcOEoIS0V</a></p>&mdash; SO en Español (@esStackOverflow) <a href="https://twitter.com/esStackOverflow/status/864815633447485442">17 de mayo de 2017</a></blockquote>
<div>Todo lo que esté después de cada mensaje</div>

<div>Todo lo que esté antes de cada mensaje</div>
Este es el mensaje de otro usuario.
<div>Todo lo que esté después de cada mensaje</div>

<script async src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

#### Alternativas

Te recomiendo leer la página de ayuda para desarrolladores de Twitter: [Embed a Single Tweet](https://dev.twitter.com/web/embedded-tweets), donde te muestran las diferentes alternativas para embeber un tweet en tu página.

#### Nota importante de seguridad

Esto responde directamente a tu pregunta. No obstante, **de ninguna manera es seguro**. ¿Qué le impide a un usuario enviar algo como lo siguiente?

```
<div onclick="console.log('código inyectado');">Texto</div>
```

La única forma de permitir eficientemente que el usuario agregue tags es con un formato de marcado que proceses de tu lado.

> Cuando imprimas código ingresado por un usuario, sólo es seguro si se usa [**`htmlspecialchars()`**](http://php.net/manual/es/function.htmlspecialchars.php) (que obviamente escapa todos los tags y te haría perder el formato). No le creas a nadie que te convenza de otra cosa.

Comment: Muchas gracias, respuesta muy clara. Me ha servido, pensaba que el script iba siempre después del código. En cuanto al tema de seguridad, no me había dado cuenta que se podía hacer eso, pero 'htmlspecialchars()` hace que se vean las etiquetas como tal. Ma pasaría con las etiquetas de negrita y cursiva por ejemplo.

Comment: @JetLagFox exacto, no estoy dándote una solución concreta a esa parte porque no es sencillo, es un tema para largo, y se escapa del alcance de esta pregunta. Sólo respondí "es con un formato de marcado". Sea cual fuera la solución que implementes (tuya o de un tercero), va a requerir procesar todo el texto. No hay una respuesta mágica.